# Functor whose values on morphisms are monomorphisms

Tags: category-theory, terminology, abstract-algebra

Is there a name for a functor whose values on morphisms are monomorphisms?

Comment: Filtration perhaps?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I've looked into Wikipedia. Filtration is something about totally ordered sets and thus is unrelated with my notion. Why on the Earth have you decided it is related with filtration?

Comment: I don't know why Martin decided what he did, or if he did decide anything at all. Perhaps next time you can give waaaay more background and self work about your usually weird questions, @porton ? That way it could be no many on Earth would decide something you believe is not unrelated to "your notion" ...

Comment: Think about it a little bit more. A filtration is a functor on $(\mathbb{Z},\leq)$ valued in monomorphisms. Now it is natural to consider other orders, or even categories. Voila, filtrations in a general sense.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg it seems to me though, that some order in the domain category is essential to filtrations (in the common usage). If we take that away , as porton suggests, can we still say something interesting and somehow connected to the word "filtration"? I am a bit surprised that filtrations are not really well covered in ncats. A better coverage can be found in wikipedia.

Comment: Can someone suggest any reference where *generalized filtrations* can be found?